# How to properly mount a repo subdirectory in github actions service container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, github-actions

I want to mount a directory from my github repo into a postgres container in a github actions workflow like this:

```
volumes:
- ${{ github.workspace }}/pg:/pg
```

but later on in the same work flow steps the folder appears to be empty (it is not):

```
- run: docker exec containername ls pg
```

if i mount the entire repo like this:

```
volumes:
- ${{ github.workspace }}:/ws
```

and then list the directory it is full of files:

```
- run: docker exec containername ls ws/pg
```

why is this so?

Comment: How is that PostgreSQL container being set up? Please include all the relevant GHA workflow in your question. Thanks!